# How to change direction of X Value?

Tags: eclipse, ide, direction

I'm using Eclipse IDE, and I am trying to change the direction of an X axis.

So I use(simplified) :

```
int x = 50;
while (true){
synchronized(c){
c.clear();
X = X+5;
}
if (X == 500 ){
X = X-5;
}
```

It will go to 500, then to 495 then keep going to 500 like a bump. I want it to change the direction to `X-5;`? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use (simplified)

```
        int x = 50;
        int inc = 5;
        while (true) {
            synchronized (c) {
                c.clear();
                x = x + inc;
            }
            if (x >= 500) {
                inc = -5;
            }
            if (x <= 0) {
                inc = 5;
            }
        }
```